# What needs to be in the constructor and what needs to be in the setter functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

The objective is to output the same data as the first program. 
The first program requires manual input of the room number and room cost. The second (problematic) program requires it to auto populate with the room number and room cost being hard coded in to an array within the main.
A default constructor of the class "room" is needed to populate the array and add setter functions to set the values of the room number and cost.
The objective of the whole program is to create the array, populate with test data and then list the data about the rooms.
Program 1 (manual in put) - this works fine;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class room 
{
    int roomNo;
    float roomCost;
public:    
    void GetData ();        
    void PutData ();        
};
void room::GetData ()   
{
    cout << "\n\tEnter room number : ";
    cin >> roomNo;
    cout << "\n\tEnter room cost : ";
    cin >> roomCost;
} 
void room::PutData ()       
{
    cout << "\n\t\t\t" << roomNo << " \t|\t " << roomCost;
} 

int main () 
{
    int roomNo;

    room roomList[10];  

    for (roomNo = 0; roomNo < 10; roomNo++)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter details of " << roomNo + 1 << " room" << endl;
        roomList[roomNo].GetData ();
    }
    cout <<"\n*******************************************************************************";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t   Room Details";
    cout <<"\n*******************************************************************************";
    cout << "\n\t\t Room Number \t|     Cost per Night";
    cout << "\n\t\t--------------------------------------";
        for (roomNo = 0; roomNo < 2; roomNo++)
        roomList[roomNo].PutData();     

    getchar ();
    getchar ();
}
```

Second (problematic) program;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class room 
{
    int roomNo;
    float roomCost;
public:
    room();
    void PutData ();        
};
room::room()
{
    cout<<"\n\t\t\t"<<roomNo<<" \t|\t "<<roomCost;
}
void room::PutData ()       
{
    cout << "\n\t\t\t" << roomNo << " \t|\t " << roomCost;
} 

int main () 
{
    int roomNo[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    float roomCost[10] = {100.00, 90.00, 85.50, 80.00, 80.00, 50.00, 50.00, 45.50, 45.50, 40.00};

    room roomList[10];  //Statement 3 : Creating Array of 3 Employees

    cout <<"\n*******************************************************************************";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t   Room Details";
    cout <<"\n*******************************************************************************";
    cout << "\n\t\t Room Number \t|     Cost per Night";
    cout << "\n\t\t--------------------------------------";

    for (int roomNo = 0; roomNo < 10; roomNo++)
    roomList[roomNo].PutData();

    getchar ();
    getchar ();
}
```

Comment: A constructor should initialize the object to a valid state, nothing more. It shouldn't do output or input. Your constructor in the second example doesn't do any initialization, it just print the *uninitialized* members and their *indeterminate* values which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: FYI: `int roomNo[10]` has no reason to exist in the second example. It's hidden by the loop variable anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that   `roomNo` and `roomCost` never actually get set to anything for each `room` instance. The class won't automatically pull from the arrays you define in `main`.

Additionally,

```
roomList[roomNo].PutData();
```

Accesses uninitialized data:

```
void room::PutData ()       
{
    cout << "\n\t\t\t" << roomNo << " \t|\t " << roomCost;
}
```

(The constructor has the same problem)

The solution is to *initialize* each `room` with the correct data. I recommend using the constructor:

```
room(int _roomNum, float _roomCost) : roomNo(_roomNum), roomCost(_roomCost)
{}
```

Then use a `vector` to initialize (instead of `room roomsList[10]`)

```
std::vector<room> rooms;
rooms.reserve(10);
for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   rooms.emplace_back(roomNo[i], roomCost[i]);
```

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/S8CVVJwuRTQmksCs)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, this is my first experience with vector and blimey is does save some headaches. Thank you for the live demo also, much appreciated.

Comment: @rodders: You're welcome. Just FYI as the question asker you are able to both "upvote" *and* mark answers as accepted. For now the answer is only marked as accepted. (If this was your intent please disregard)

Answer (score 0):

You should have two setters, one for each member, and then write your loop like

```
for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
{
    roomList[n].setNumber(roomNo[n]);
    roomList[n].setCost(roomCost[n]);
}
```

(On a side note, you should do the same with the first program and handle user input in `main`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I have plaid about with this now and it makes much better sense.